# How to remove border of UISearchbar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

As per as design I tried to remove the border of uisearchbar but failed. can you please help or suggest?

[image]

I want to create like below design.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

If this custom search bar?
Mb you need something like this:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
```

This removes background. And after this set this:

```
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Or mb you are need to try this:

```
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor YOUR_COLOR_HERE] CGColor];
```

And another case:

```
topSearchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Mb this help you

Answer (score 0):

After the trial, I found a solution which is working for me. I set the color like super view's color. That's why it is not visible and then I wrote some lines of code in viewDidLoad().

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.black
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To obtain this design make below changes in storyboard.

[image]

and

[image]

then add below code into your `viewdidload` or whatever you want.

```
self.bar.layer.cornerRadius = self.bar.frame.height/2
    self.bar.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

then I think you will get your desire design.let me know if it works or not .